# Circle and arrow on a single term of equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, tikz-arrows, arrows, circles

I want to create an equation with this circle and arrow on a single term by a single command. I want to obtain an equation similar to this:

[image]

I wrote this until now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
   \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
   \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
   \[\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}= \mathcircled{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
   \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
\tikz[baseline=(math.base)] {\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$}; \draw[-{Triangle[open]}] (math.north east) -- +(0.3,0.3)}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
   \[\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}= \mathcircled{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Circled math with arrow]

Edit:

With a number:

```
\tikz[baseline=(math.base)] {\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$}; \draw[-{Triangle[open]}] (math.north east) -- +(0.3,0.3) node[above right]{1}}%
```

[image: Same math, but with a number above the arrow]

Comment: +1 I was trying to access `(math)` via a `tikzpicture` after the `\[...\]` but faild. Any idea why one cannot globally access the `(math)` node?

Comment: @daleif: I think you need the `remember picture` option for the first `tikzpicture`. Better would be to look into the `tikzmark` package. You also need `overlay` - p. 259 in the manual

Comment: I added those, but nothing happend. Ahh, well I'll try again

Comment: @daleif: Ahh - ok. The weird double `newcommand` definition, that I do not understand is messing with normal node access. The straight forward solution by Vincent and others do not have this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617833/8650