# Circle and arrow on a single term of a math equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, tikz-arrows, arrows, circles

I want to create an equation with this circle and arrow on a single term by a single command. I want to obtain an equation similar to this:

[image]

I need a new command `\mathcircled` with 2 parameters `\mathcircled[0]{f(x)}`. "0" is the number that will inserted on top of the arrow, "f(x)" is the term to circle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
     ...
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
   \[\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}= \mathcircled[0]{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Is there any chance, that you can help me with my problem. Your answers are really great and work very well. But is it possible to have an arrow going down, when expression is in a denominator?
I would like to have something like this: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Db7.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Db7.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be close to what you're looking for. It doesn't look that good in a fraction, but I don't really see how such a construction could really look better in this context.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand\mathcircled[3][\displaystyle]{%
    \mathord{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
            \useasboundingbox (0,0) node[circle, inner sep=1.5pt] {\phantom{\(#1#3\)}} -- ++(0,.4) node {};
            \node[circle, draw, inner sep=1pt] (X) at (0,0) {\(#1#3\)};
            \draw[-{Triangle[open]}] (X.north east) -- ++(.25,.25);
            \path (X.north east) ++(.35,.35) node {\(\scriptstyle #2\)};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
    \[ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} = \mathcircled{0}{\frac{\sin x}{x}} = 0
    \qquad
    \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x \biggl[ 2\mathcircled[\textstyle]{1}{\frac{\sin x}{x}} + 4 \frac{\tan x}{x} \biggr]}{[\cos x + 2 \frac{\sin x}{x}]} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: if i use this in a fraction it doesn't work well

Comment: @GerardoSchiavo what do you mean exactly by "it doesn't work well"?

Comment: Like this: https://i.imgur.com/nAFM7fD.png

Comment: @GerardoSchiavo I changed a bit the definition so that the math style can be specified in the optional argument.

Comment: Just an humble comment. But between the 2 and \sin x /x there is a bit of the space. Is it possible to have a small space to separate the 2 with the circled fraction?

Comment: @Sebastiano yes, the 2 and the circle were indeed very close. I added a little more space to the bounding box.

Comment: @Vincent Thank you very much to have take my advice :-)..and rewelcome.

Comment: Off-topic. But the limit is 1 when x \to 0 :-))))) Where the user have seen this "notable" limit? :-))))

Comment: @Sebastiano the limit is 1 when x -> 0, but not when x -> \infty ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I propose a solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-arrow}

\begin{document}

   \[\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}= \circlenode[linewidth=0.6pt, linecolor=Tomato, framesep=0pt]{A}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1
    \uput{32pt}[ur](A){\Rnode{B}{1}}
    \ncline[linecolor=Tomato, arrowinset=0, arrowscale=1.25, ArrowFill=false]{->}{A}{B}
   \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This code give me some error.

Comment: @GerardoSchiavo: pstricks code, traditionally, is compiled with the cycle `latex> dvips > pstopdf`, because pdflatex cannot make the computations required by Adobe Postscript code. Other method: compile with  `xelatex --shell-escape`.

Comment: Just a curiosity: but the limit is 1 when x \to 0 :-))))) Where the user have seen this "notable" limit? :-))))

Comment: @Sebastiano: I was also surprised by this formulation, but I thought  that the O.P .had written a formula to show explicitly his latex problem, independently of the meaning of the formula.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a TikZ solution similar to @Vincent's but with somewhat simplified TikZ code and slightly improved horizontal spacing.

The command usage is `\mathcircled[<style>]{<limit>}{<circled math>}`. The optional argument has default `\displaystyle`.

[image]

```
\[\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}= \mathcircled{0}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1\]
```

If your circled math is not in `\displaystyle`, use the optional argument:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\mathcircled[3][\displaystyle]{\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0,anchor=base](A){$#1#3$};
    \draw[overlay,->](A.north east)--++(.3,.3)node[shift={(.1,.1)}]{$\scriptstyle#2$};
}}

\begin{document}
   \[\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}= \mathcircled{0}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1\]
   
   \hspace{2cm}
   
   \[\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x \biggl[ 2\mathcircled[\textstyle]{1}{\frac{\sin x}{x}} + 4 \frac{\tan x}{x} \biggr]}{[\cos x + 2 \frac{\sin x}{x}]} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice all (question and answers).