# Circle and arrow on a single term of a math equation - arrow up and down

Tags: math-mode, arrows, circles

Is there any chance, that you can help me with my problem? I've already used answers from topic: [Circle and arrow on a single term of a math equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617826/circle-and-arrow-on-a-single-term-of-a-math-equation/690270#690270) It works very well. But is it possible to have an arrow going down, when expression is in a denominator? I would like to have something like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you edit into your question how your code currently looks please, a minimal example that produces as much as possible of that image?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a macro that does what you want.

The usage is `\goesto[<tikz options>]{<text>}{<angle>}{<content>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tolength}{.7} % length of arrows in cm from node center
\newcommand{\goesto}[4][]% usage: \goesto[<tikz options>]{<text>}{<angle>}{<content>}
  {\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[inner sep=0,anchor=base](A){$#4$};
    \path(A)--++(0,{(\tolength+.15)*sin(#3)}); % vertical space to avoid overlapping other lines
    \draw[overlay,->,#1](A)--++(#3:\tolength)node[shift={(#3:.15)}]{\scriptsize #2};
  }} 

\begin{document}
This is the line above. This is the line above. This is the line above. 
\[
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac
    {\goesto[blue]{0}{45}{\frac{1}{n^2}}+\goesto[blue]{0}{45}{\frac{1}{n}}}
    {\goesto[shorten <=1pt]{unchanged}{225}{6}+\goesto[orange, thick, densely dotted]{0}{-45}{\frac{8}{n^3}}}
    =\frac{0}{6}=0
\]
This is the line below. This is the line below. This is the line below. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much! Your solution is perfect!

Comment: @daria: You're welcome. It may seem strange, but on this site we don't usually give thanks in the comments. The way to show appreciation is to [upvote all answers that are helpful and to accept the one that you find most helpful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).